# How to remove query string from static resource in WordPress?

Tags: customization, query-string

I have this type of **query string**, Like:

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js?ba0a5a&ba0a5a
>   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js?ba0a5a&ba0a5a
>   https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?ba0a5a&ba0a5a

How to remove, for example, **?ba0a5a&ba0a5a**, from the URL.

Comment: These don't look "normal" and WP doesn't natively load jQuery from a CDN. I would recommend to determine where are they coming from and _why_ do they get queries attached first.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the **Query Strings** using this code in your `functions.php`

```
function _remove_query_strings( $src ){ 
    $parts = explode( '?', $src );  
    return $parts[0]; 
} 
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_query_strings', 15, 1 ); 
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_query_strings', 15, 1 ); //not need to in your case since it's for the CSS files
```

Comment: While this answers question literally, I highly recommend to never do this unconditionally for _all_ scripts/styles. It's very normal for WP core and extensions to use query strings for versioning of assets (which is suboptimal technique from cache perspective, but it is what it is).

Comment: Use it "at your own risk" I should've added. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, wouldn't this break cache-revving via url params? I think OP should find where those scripts are enqued and remove the query-strings manually. do a global search in the theme for enqueue_script &/or the urls that have query-strings added to them & see if there's a simpler (more concise less global) solution (like just removing the query strings or adding an exception to the filter which is adding them in the first place).

Comment: This function removes only ?v,?var type query string but not remove ?ba0a5a&ba0a5a this type query string.
This function not working.